# Fault Analysis Service missing from Service Fabric Cluster

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I am planning to use service fabric chaos to test my service, however starting it gives me the following error:

`Start-ServiceFabricChaos : An error occurred during this operation.  Please check the trace logs for more details.
At line:1 char:1
+ Start-ServiceFabricChaos -TimeToRunMinute 60 -MaxConcurrentFaults 3 - ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Microsoft.Servi...usterConnection:ClusterConnection) [Start-ServiceFabricChaos], FabricException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StartChaosCommandErrorId,Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Powershell.StartChaos`

I don't see any trace files but upon looking at Service Fabric explorer, I don't see the `Fault Analysis Service` listed under `System` application. The only system services I see are `clustermanagerservice`, `failovermanagerservice`, `namingservice`.

What is causing the `fault analysis service` to be missing ?

Control panel shows the following bits installed:
Microsoft Azure Service Fabric         6.2.283.9494
Microsoft Azure Service Fabric SDK     3.1.283.9494

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service only starts if minimum 5 node dev cluster used. After resetting the cluster by following the link here, it worked as expected. All services showed up.

[reset SF cluster](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/02595752-37d4-43f6-94c9-d1799a0ec608/restart-service-fabric-cluster?forum=AzureServiceFabric)